# Why does my sin calculating code in C return the wrong value?

Tags: c, equation-solving

I want to calculate the sinus of user inputs using my own functions based on this equation:

`sin(x) = sum_(i=0)^n (-1)^i * (x^(2 i + 1)/((2 i + 1)!))`

[image: Picture of equation]

I have this code and to my understandings I do exactly the same as what's written in the equation:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int faculty(int factor)
{
    int result = 1;

    if (factor > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= factor; i++)
        {
            result = result * i;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        result = 1;
    }

    return result;
}

double my_sin(double x, int n)
{
    double my_sin = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < n ; j++)
    {
        double i = (double)j;
        double faculty_j = (double)faculty(2*j+1);
        my_sin = my_sin + (pow((-1.0), i) * (pow(x, (double)(2.0 * i + 1.0)) / faculty_j));
    }

    return my_sin;
}

int main()
{
    int n = 0;
    double x = 0;

    printf("x=");
    scanf("%lf", &x);

    printf("n=");
    scanf("%i", &n);

    printf("sin(%i)=", (int)x);
    printf("%lf\n", my_sin(x, n));

    return 0;
}
```

However for example when I use `x = 8` and `n = 5` I get `sin(8)=149` as a result. I tried debugging the code for some time now but I have no idea where the problem might be or how to find out what the problem is.

---

Updated code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

long int factorial(int factor)
{
    long int result = 1;

    if (factor > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= factor; i++)
        {
            result = result * i;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        result = 1;
    }

    return result;
}

double my_pow(double a, double b)
{
    if (b == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    double result = a;
    double increment = a;
    double i, j;

    for (i = 1; i < b; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j < a; j++)
        {
            result += increment;
        }
        increment = result;
    }
    return result;
}

double my_sin(double x, int n)
{
    double my_sin = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < n ; j++)
    {
        double i = (double)j;
        double faculty_j = (double)factorial(2*i+1);
        my_sin = my_sin + (my_pow((-1.0), i) * (my_pow(x, 2.0 * i + 1.0) / faculty_j));
    }

    return my_sin;
}

int main()
{
    int n = 0;
    double x = 0;

    printf("x=");
    scanf_s("%lf", &x);

    printf("n=");
    scanf_s("%i", &n);

    printf("sin(%i)=", (int)x);
    printf("%lf\n", my_sin(x, n));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int my_sin`, really?

Comment: You have declared a function `int my_sin(double x, int n)` that returns a `double`. That will never work well.

Comment: What is the *expected* result? And to help with debugging, split complex expressions into simpler expressions, storing the intermediate results in temporary variables. That will make it much easier to see when and where calculations start to go wrong. Also please read [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: @AdrianMole sure it works, because of conversion

Comment: The Taylor series converges much faster when x is near zero. It will converge with arbitrary x, but requires much larger n.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I added "well" to the end of my comment.

Comment: your `faculty` should be named *`factorial`*. Also, any use of `pow` function is a grave mistake! You should use repeated multiplications instead - hint, see what you can save from previous loop iterations.

Comment: `2*j` it can overflow

Comment: and faculty result will overflow very quickly

Comment: So yeah. The problems are numerous - not only is using this to calculate sin(8) not mathematically sound, none of the functions you're using produce as good quality results that you would really need, and you're rounding the end result to an *int* so in the end you would **~always get 0 when it works!**

Comment: Okay now I changed `my_sin` to return a double, I'm using my own `pow` function and I changed the factorial function to use `long int`. Also I changed `2*j` to `2*i` (`i` is a `double`) but I still get incorrect results.

Comment: @Emmi The problem is your expectations on the equation.

Comment: Use radians. Wiki says: The trigonometric functions also have simple and elegant series expansions when radians are used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is not necessarily your code. It's just your expectations on the equation. I tested the Taylor series for n=5 in Wolfram Alpha and subtracted sin(x) from the series, using the query

```
(sum (-1)^i * x^(2i+1)/(2i+1)!, i=0 to 5) - sin(x)
```

to see the error.

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28sum+%28-1%29%5Ei+*+x%5E%282i%2B1%29%2F%282i%2B1%29%21%2C+i%3D0+to+5%29+-+sin%28x%29

[image]

As you can see, the series does a very good approximation when x is around 0, but when x goes above 3, the errors starts to be huge, and they are growing extremely fast. At x=8, the error has the size 67, which is obviously useless. To get a reasonable approximation, you need to use around n=15. Only five is way to little.

What you should do here is to take advantage of the fact that sin(x) = sin(x + k * 2 * PI) where k is an arbitrary integer. And if x is negative, you can just simple use the fact that sin(x) = -sin(-x). I'm showing a simple example of how it's done:

```
double my_sin(double x, int n)
{
    double my_sin = 0;
    double sign = 1.0;

    // sin(-x) = -sin(x)
    // This does not improve accuracy. It's just to make the rest simpler
    if(x<0) {
        x=-x;
        sign *= -1;
    }

    // sin(x) = sin(k*2*PI + x)
    x -= 2*PI*floor(x/(2*PI));

    // Continue as usual

    return sign * my_sin;
}
```

You want to be as close to x=0 as possible. In order to improve this even further, you can use the fact that sin(x) = -sin(x+PI), as shown below.

The above is enough to keep everything in the interval [0, PI], but we can actually do better than that by using some more clever math. We can use the fact that sin(x) is symmetric around x=PI/2 + k*PI. So sin(PI/2 -x) = sin(PI/2 + x). Utilizing that will keep you in the interval [0, PI/2] and when you're in that interval, n=2 is enough to get an error below 0.005. And for n=5, the error is below 10^-7. You can add this after the previous steps:

```
// sin(x) = -sin(x+PI)
if(x>PI) {
    x-=PI;
    sign *= -1;
}

// sin(PI/2 -x) = sin(PI/2 + x)
if(x>PI/2) 
    x = PI - x;
```

However, there is one bug in your code. Remember that the case j=n should be included, so change

```
for (int j = 0; j < n ; j++)
```

to

```
for (int j = 0; j <= n ; j++)
```

An alternative is to always call the function with 1 added to the argument.

And just for clarity. Remember that the Taylor series expects `x` to be in radians. If you're using degrees, you'll get the wrong result.

Just for completeness, here is the full function with a few other fixes that does not affect correctness but performance and readability:

```
double my_sin(double x, int n)
{
    double ret = 0;
    double sign = 1.0;

    if(x<0) {
        x=-x;
        sign *= -1;
    }

    x -= 2*PI*floor(x/(2*PI));

    if(x>PI) {
        x-=PI;
        sign *= -1;
    }

    if(x>PI/2) 
        x = PI - x;

    size_t denominator = 1;
    double numerator = x;
    int s = -1;

    for (int j = 0; j <= n ; j++) {
        denominator *= 2*j + 1;
        s *= -1;

        ret += s * numerator / denominator;

        numerator *= x*x;
    }

    return sign*ret;
}
```

#### Aiming for a certain precision

Say that you want 3 correct decimal digits. Then we can utilize the fact that the numerator grows slower than the denominator and do something like this:

```
    size_t denominator = 1;
    double numerator = x;
    double term;
    int s = -1;
    int j = 0;
    double tolerance = 0.001;

    do {
        denominator *= 2*j + 1;
        j++;
        s *= -1;

        term = numerator / denominator;

        ret += s * term;

        numerator *= x*x;
    } while(abs(term) > tolerance);
```

Answer (score 3):

There are many problems in your code:

- the `factorial` function computes using integer arithmetic, which has a limited range. It will overflow with undefined behavior for `n > 13` with 32-bit `int` or `long`.
- the `my_pow()` function is incorrect: it does not work for negative values hence gives an inorrect result for `my_pow(-1, ...)`.

You should also first reduce `x` to a number between 0 and PI/2 and compute the terms of the series incrementally.

Here is a modified version with a test suite:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

long int factorial(int factor) {
    long int result = 1;

    if (factor > 0) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= factor; i++) {
            result = result * i;
        }
    } else {
        result = 1;
    }
    return result;
}

double my_pow(double a, double b) {
    if (b == 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    double result = a;
    double increment = a;
    double i, j;

    for (i = 1; i < b; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j < a; j++) {
            result += increment;
        }
        increment = result;
    }
    return result;
}

double my_sin(double x, int n) {
    double my_sin = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        double i = (double)j;
        double faculty_j = (double)factorial(2 * i + 1);
        my_sin = my_sin + (my_pow((-1.0), i) * (my_pow(x, 2.0 * i + 1.0) / faculty_j));
    }
    return my_sin;
}

double my_sin2(double x, int n) {
    double my_sin, term, sign = 1.0;
    if (x < 0) {
        x = -x;
        sign = -sign;
    }
    if (x >= 2 * M_PI) {
        x = fmod(x, 2 * M_PI);
    }
    if (x > M_PI) {
        x -= M_PI;
        sign = -sign;
    }
    if (x > M_PI / 2) {
        x = M_PI - x;
    }
    my_sin = term = x * sign;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        term = -term * x * x / ((2 * i) * (2 * i + 1));
        my_sin += term;
    }
    return my_sin;
}

int main() {
    int i, n = 16, steps = 100;
    double x1 = -7.0, x2 = 7.0;
#if 0
    printf("n=");
    scanf("%i", &n);
    printf("x1=");
    scanf("%lf", &x1);
    printf("x2=");
    scanf("%lf", &x2);
    printf("steps=");
    scanf("%i", &steps);
#endif
    char buf1[20];
    char buf2[20];
    snprintf(buf1, sizeof(buf1), "my_sin(x,%d)", n);
    snprintf(buf2, sizeof(buf2), "my_sin2(x,%d)", n);
    printf("%17s  %17s  %17s  %17s  %17s  %17s\n",
           "x", "sin(x)", buf1, "error1", buf2, "error2");
    for (i = 0; i <= steps; i++) {
        double x = x1 + (x2 - x1) * ((double)i / steps);
        double s = sin(x);
        double s1 = my_sin(x, n);
        double s2 = my_sin2(x, n);
        printf("%17.14f  %17.14f  %17.14f  %17.14f  %17.14f  %17.14f\n",
               x, s, s1, s1 - s, s2, s2 - s);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
                x             sin(x)       my_sin(x,16)             error1      my_sin2(x,16)             error2
-7.00000000000000  -0.65698659871879  -5.77359164449339  -5.11660504577460  -0.65698659871879  -0.00000000000000
-6.86000000000000  -0.54535677064030  -5.65811981160352  -5.11276304096322  -0.54535677064030   0.00000000000000
-6.72000000000000  -0.42305539714300  -5.54264797871365  -5.11959258157066  -0.42305539714300  -0.00000000000000
-6.58000000000000  -0.29247567242987  -5.42717614582379  -5.13470047339392  -0.29247567242987  -0.00000000000000
-6.44000000000000  -0.15617278154321  -5.31170431293392  -5.15553153139071  -0.15617278154321  -0.00000000000000
-6.30000000000000  -0.01681390048435  -5.19623248004405  -5.17941857955970  -0.01681390048435  -0.00000000000000
-6.16000000000000   0.12287399510655  -5.08076064715418  -5.20363464226073   0.12287399510655  -0.00000000000000
-6.02000000000000   0.26015749143047  -4.96528881426431  -5.22544630569478   0.26015749143047  -0.00000000000000
-5.88000000000000   0.39235022399145  -4.84981698137445  -5.24216720536590   0.39235022399145  -0.00000000000000
-5.74000000000000   0.51686544439743  -4.73434514848458  -5.25121059288201   0.51686544439743  -0.00000000000000
-5.60000000000000   0.63126663787232  -4.61887331559471  -5.25013995346703   0.63126663787232  -0.00000000000000
-5.46000000000000   0.73331520099566  -4.50340148270484  -5.23671668370050   0.73331520099566  -0.00000000000000
-5.32000000000000   0.82101424671125  -4.38792964981498  -5.20894389652622   0.82101424671125  -0.00000000000000
-5.18000000000000   0.89264767942823  -4.27245781692511  -5.16510549635334   0.89264767942823   0.00000000000000
-5.04000000000000   0.94681377559261  -4.15698598403524  -5.10379975962785   0.94681377559261  -0.00000000000000
-4.90000000000000   0.98245261262433  -4.04151415114537  -5.02396676376970   0.98245261262433  -0.00000000000000
-4.76000000000000   0.99886680949041  -3.92604231825550  -4.92490912774592   0.99886680949041   0.00000000000000
-4.62000000000000   0.99573517306225  -3.81057048536564  -4.80630565842788   0.99573517306225   0.00000000000000
-4.48000000000000   0.97311898322517  -3.69509865247577  -4.66821763570094   0.97311898322517   0.00000000000000
-4.34000000000000   0.93146079375324  -3.57962681958590  -4.51108761333914   0.93146079375324   0.00000000000000
-4.20000000000000   0.87157577241359  -3.46415498669603  -4.33573075910962   0.87157577241359   0.00000000000000
-4.06000000000000   0.79463574975740  -3.34868315380617  -4.14331890356356   0.79463574975740   0.00000000000000
-3.92000000000000   0.70214628873081  -3.23321132091630  -3.93535760964710   0.70214628873081   0.00000000000000
-3.78000000000000   0.59591722380776  -3.11773948802643  -3.71365671183419   0.59591722380776  -0.00000000000000
-3.64000000000000   0.47802724613534  -3.00226765513656  -3.48029490127191   0.47802724613534   0.00000000000000
-3.50000000000000   0.35078322768962  -2.88679582224669  -3.23757904993631   0.35078322768962   0.00000000000000
-3.36000000000000   0.21667508038738  -2.77132398935683  -2.98799906974421   0.21667508038738   0.00000000000000
-3.22000000000000   0.07832703347086  -2.65585215646696  -2.73417918993782   0.07832703347086   0.00000000000000
-3.08000000000000  -0.06155371742991  -2.54038032357709  -2.47882660614718  -0.06155371742991   0.00000000000000
-2.94000000000000  -0.20022998472177  -2.42490849068722  -2.22467850596545  -0.20022998472177   0.00000000000000
-2.80000000000000  -0.33498815015591  -2.30943665779736  -1.97444850764145  -0.33498815015590   0.00000000000000
-2.66000000000000  -0.46319126493035  -2.19396482490749  -1.73077355997714  -0.46319126493035   0.00000000000000
-2.52000000000000  -0.58233064952408  -2.07849299201762  -1.49616234249354  -0.58233064952408   0.00000000000000
-2.38000000000000  -0.69007498355694  -1.96302115912775  -1.27294617557082  -0.69007498355694   0.00000000000000
-2.24000000000000  -0.78431592508442  -1.84754932623788  -1.06323340115346  -0.78431592508442   0.00000000000000
-2.10000000000000  -0.86320936664887  -1.73207749334802  -0.86886812669914  -0.86320936664887   0.00000000000000
-1.96000000000000  -0.92521152078817  -1.61660566045815  -0.69139413966998  -0.92521152078817   0.00000000000000
-1.82000000000000  -0.96910912888046  -1.50113382756828  -0.53202469868783  -0.96910912888046   0.00000000000000
-1.68000000000000  -0.99404320219808  -1.38566199467841  -0.39161879248034  -0.99404320219808  -0.00000000000000
-1.54000000000000  -0.99952583060548  -1.27019016178855  -0.27066433118307  -0.99952583060548   0.00000000000000
-1.40000000000000  -0.98544972998846  -1.15471832889868  -0.16926859891022  -0.98544972998846   0.00000000000000
-1.26000000000000  -0.95209034159052  -1.03924649600881  -0.08715615441829  -0.95209034159052  -0.00000000000000
-1.12000000000000  -0.90010044217651  -0.92377466311894  -0.02367422094244  -0.90010044217651   0.00000000000000
-0.98000000000000  -0.83049737049197  -0.80830283022907   0.02219454026290  -0.83049737049197  -0.00000000000000
-0.84000000000000  -0.74464311997086  -0.69283099733921   0.05181212263165  -0.74464311997086   0.00000000000000
-0.70000000000000  -0.64421768723769  -0.57735916444934   0.06685852278835  -0.64421768723769   0.00000000000000
-0.56000000000000  -0.53118619792088  -0.46188733155947   0.06929886636141  -0.53118619792088   0.00000000000000
-0.42000000000000  -0.40776045305957  -0.34641549866960   0.06134495438997  -0.40776045305957  -0.00000000000000
-0.28000000000000  -0.27635564856411  -0.23094366577974   0.04541198278438  -0.27635564856411   0.00000000000000
-0.14000000000000  -0.13954311464424  -0.11547183288987   0.02407128175437  -0.13954311464424   0.00000000000000
 0.00000000000000   0.00000000000000   0.00000000000000   0.00000000000000   0.00000000000000   0.00000000000000
 0.14000000000000   0.13954311464424   0.11547183288987  -0.02407128175437   0.13954311464424   0.00000000000000
 0.28000000000000   0.27635564856411   0.23094366577974  -0.04541198278438   0.27635564856411   0.00000000000000
 0.42000000000000   0.40776045305957   0.34641549866960  -0.06134495438997   0.40776045305957   0.00000000000000
 0.56000000000000   0.53118619792088   0.46188733155947  -0.06929886636141   0.53118619792088   0.00000000000000
 0.70000000000000   0.64421768723769   0.57735916444934  -0.06685852278835   0.64421768723769   0.00000000000000
 0.84000000000000   0.74464311997086   0.69283099733921  -0.05181212263165   0.74464311997086   0.00000000000000
 0.98000000000000   0.83049737049197   0.80830283022907  -0.02219454026290   0.83049737049197   0.00000000000000
 1.12000000000000   0.90010044217650   0.20895817141848  -0.69114227075803   0.90010044217650   0.00000000000000
 1.26000000000000   0.95209034159052   0.23507794284579  -0.71701239874473   0.95209034159052   0.00000000000000
 1.40000000000000   0.98544972998846   0.26119771427310  -0.72425201571536   0.98544972998846   0.00000000000000
 1.54000000000000   0.99952583060548   0.28731748570041  -0.71220834490507   0.99952583060548   0.00000000000000
 1.68000000000000   0.99404320219808   0.31343725712772  -0.68060594507036   0.99404320219808   0.00000000000000
 1.82000000000000   0.96910912888046   0.33955702855503  -0.62955210032543   0.96910912888046  -0.00000000000000
 1.96000000000000   0.92521152078817   0.36567679998234  -0.55953472080583   0.92521152078817   0.00000000000000
 2.10000000000000   0.86320936664887  -2.81259124559189  -3.67580061224076   0.86320936664887   0.00000000000000
 2.24000000000000   0.78431592508442  -3.00009732863135  -3.78441325371577   0.78431592508442  -0.00000000000000
 2.38000000000000   0.69007498355694  -3.18760341167081  -3.87767839522775   0.69007498355694  -0.00000000000000
 2.52000000000000   0.58233064952408  -3.37510949471027  -3.95744014423435   0.58233064952408  -0.00000000000000
 2.66000000000000   0.46319126493035  -3.56261557774973  -4.02580684268007   0.46319126493035   0.00000000000000
 2.80000000000000   0.33498815015591  -3.75012166078919  -4.08510981094509   0.33498815015591  -0.00000000000000
 2.94000000000000   0.20022998472177  -3.93762774382865  -4.13785772855042   0.20022998472177  -0.00000000000000
 3.08000000000000   0.06155371742991  -15.52969329095525  -15.59124700838516   0.06155371742991  -0.00000000000000
 3.22000000000000  -0.07832703347086  -16.23558844054412  -16.15726140707325  -0.07832703347086  -0.00000000000000
 3.36000000000000  -0.21667508038738  -16.94148359013299  -16.72480850974561  -0.21667508038738  -0.00000000000000
 3.50000000000000  -0.35078322768962  -17.64737873972186  -17.29659551203224  -0.35078322768962  -0.00000000000000
 3.64000000000000  -0.47802724613534  -18.35327388931075  -17.87524664317541  -0.47802724613534  -0.00000000000000
 3.78000000000000  -0.59591722380777  -19.05916903889963  -18.46325181509186  -0.59591722380776   0.00000000000000
 3.92000000000000  -0.70214628873081  -19.76506418848850  -19.06291789975770  -0.70214628873081  -0.00000000000000
 4.06000000000000  -0.79463574975740  -785.98288527038937  -785.18824952063198  -0.79463574975740  -0.00000000000000
 4.20000000000000  -0.87157577241359  -813.08574338316134  -812.21416761074772  -0.87157577241359   0.00000000000000
 4.34000000000000  -0.93146079375324  -840.18860149593320  -839.25714070217998  -0.93146079375324   0.00000000000000
 4.48000000000000  -0.97311898322517  -867.29145960870540  -866.31834062548023  -0.97311898322517   0.00000000000000
 4.62000000000000  -0.99573517306225  -894.39431772147736  -893.39858254841511  -0.99573517306225  -0.00000000000000
 4.76000000000000  -0.99886680949041  -921.49717583424911  -920.49830902475867  -0.99886680949041  -0.00000000000000
 4.90000000000000  -0.98245261262433  -948.60003394702130  -947.61758133439696  -0.98245261262433   0.00000000000000
 5.04000000000000  -0.94681377559261  -218497.22569403689704  -218496.27888026129222  -0.94681377559261   0.00000000000000
 5.18000000000000  -0.89264767942823  -224566.59307442686986  -224565.70042674744036  -0.89264767942823   0.00000000000000
 5.32000000000000  -0.82101424671125  -230635.96045481678448  -230635.13944057008484  -0.82101424671125   0.00000000000000
 5.46000000000000  -0.73331520099566  -236705.32783520672820  -236704.59452000574674  -0.73331520099566   0.00000000000000
 5.60000000000000  -0.63126663787232  -242774.69521559661371  -242774.06394895873382  -0.63126663787232   0.00000000000000
 5.74000000000000  -0.51686544439743  -248844.06259598652832  -248843.54573054212960  -0.51686544439743   0.00000000000000
 5.88000000000000  -0.39235022399145  -254913.42997637641383  -254913.03762615242158  -0.39235022399145   0.00000000000000
 6.02000000000000  -0.26015749143047  -26739506.86298683285713  -26739506.60282934084535  -0.26015749143047   0.00000000000000
 6.16000000000000  -0.12287399510655  -27361355.85980049148202  -27361355.73692649602890  -0.12287399510655   0.00000000000000
 6.30000000000000   0.01681390048435  -27983204.85661410912871  -27983204.87342800945044   0.01681390048435   0.00000000000000
 6.44000000000000   0.15617278154321  -28605053.85342779010534  -28605054.00960057228804   0.15617278154321   0.00000000000000
 6.58000000000000   0.29247567242987  -29226902.85024143010378  -29226903.14271710067987   0.29247567242987   0.00000000000000
 6.72000000000000   0.42305539714300  -29848751.84705507382751  -29848752.27011046931148   0.42305539714300   0.00000000000000
 6.86000000000000   0.54535677064030  -30470600.84386872500181  -30470601.38922549411654   0.54535677064030   0.00000000000000
 7.00000000000000   0.65698659871879  -31092449.84068236500025  -31092450.49766896292567   0.65698659871879   0.00000000000000
```